# A quick Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a term for individuals of a certain gender
> My suffix is a particle with an electron owed
> My infix is a misnomer for ASCII code
> And I am a sprawling abode

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> a mansion (man / ansi / ion).